# How to add a date string to UIDatePicker SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I have a date string, and I want setDate in UIDatePicker

```
@IBOutlet weak var dp: UIDatePicker!    

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    var dateString = "02-05-2016"

    dp.date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!


}
```

not work

Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Answer (score 0):

The method dateFromString returns an optional. If the conversion fails, it returns a nil. You are getting a nil, so there must be something wrong with your format string.

I don't use date format strings often enough to have them memorized, so I'd have to go read the specs. I suggest you do that.

Comment: The date format in the question matches the date string.

Comment: This would have been better suited as a comment.

Comment: @zetanova How was it incorrect? `dd-MM-yyyy` matches a string like `02-05-2016`.